# Django - Trouble calling function in templates and return rendering the value of that function to the same page

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-request

I have a page that renders a list of objects from my database. I need to press a button that queries my database for a specific object, does some stuff in my views, and return a price value that I would like displayed on that same page in a pop-up bubble without reloading it, in place of the filler text I have. I've tried doing this by creating a form with a button that has the object's `id` in the value field, and sending that value to my original page's view, and then I call a function that handles the thing I want to do with that id. I request the object's `id`, pass it to the new view function ,  and query my database and try to return the value. I make an `if request.POST` statement in original page's view t, and change the rendered variable to the new value I want displayed. When I press the button, I get the same filler text in my pop-up bubble, and in my console I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The view engine.views.search_list didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

So it seems that I have to return a HTTP request whenever I call a view function. I've tried returning a rendered response in my new view function, and and after my check `if request.POST` and passed the new value as context:

```
return render(request, 'original_page.html', {'value':new_value})
```

I get the same error. How can I return the value I want, on the same page without getting this error? I've tried using `HttpResponse` with a blank value, and `redirect('some_place.html')` to no success. I do have an Iframe which stops my html page from reloading. Here is the code I'm using:

> HTML

```
<iframe name="submit-frame" style="display: none"></iframe>
 <form action="{% url 'search_list' %}" method="post" target="submit-frame">{% csrf_token %}
     <button name="productId" value="{{product.id}}" data-toggle="popover" data-animation="true"  data-content="{{price}}"  type="" id='button'>Reveal Price</button>
 </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    container: 'body',
     delay: { "show": 100, "fade": 100 },
})

</script>
```

> Views - Function to get new value

```
def get_price(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('productId')
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    price = item.price
    return price
```

> Views - Original Rendered View

```
def search_list(request):
results = Product.objects.all().order_by('name')
price = 'no_price'
if request.POST:
    print(request.POST.get('productId'))
    tcg_price = get_price(request)
    return render(request, 'search_result_list.html', {'tcg_price': tcg_price})
else: ...
return render(request, 'search_result_list.html', {'price': price, 'results':results})
```

Comment: I'm not clear how you are populating the bubble. Usually you would use JavaScript for that.

Comment: Also, what's confusing you about the error message? A view needs to return an HttpResponse object; so did you try returning one containing your price?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I edited my code to show how I'm creating the pop-up bubble in the html code. I thought I tried by rendering the new value as context like: `return render(request, 'search_result_list.html', {'price': price})`. Is there a different way I can return just the value as http response and use it?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do should typically be handled via an asynchronous call (AJAX). The way you currently have things set up, the form gets submitted, and the page will reload. This isn't a user-friendly experience, and is the "Web 1.0" way of doing things (also, `iframes` ... yuck!). Here's how I would change your setup:

**New View**

```
def ajax_get_price(request):
    response = {}
    product_id = request.POST.get('productId')

    try:
        item = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        response['price'] = item.price
        response['success'] = True
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        response['error'] = "Item not found!"
        response['success'] = False

    return JSONResponse(response)
```

**New Front-end Handler**

You would send data to this new "view" through an AJAX call in JavaScript. I'll use jQuery here as an example:

```
$("button[name='productId']").on("click", function() {
    var productID = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        'data': {
            'productId': productID
        },
        'type': "POST",
        'url': "{% url 'myproject:ajax_get_price' %}"
    })
    .done(function(json) {
        if(json.success == true) {
            var itemPrice = json.price;
            // TODO: Do something with the price here (show a popup, tooltip, whatever)
        } else {
            if(json.hasOwnProperty('error') {
                // TODO: Show the error
            })
        }
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        // TODO: Handle this error case also
    });
});
```

There are a few things you would need to handle above and beyond this stub:

- You will likely have to handle the CSRF (cross-site request forgery) token in a `beforeSend` call to `$.ajax()` in your JavaScript code.
- You should likely check for bogus queries in your view (is the request a GET call?) and other similar edge cases.

Comment: This doesn't really need to be a post, as it's not changing data in the db, which will avoid the csrf problem.